# Google BigQuery "WHERE (Key1,Key2) IN ( (12,34), (56,78) )" STRUCT comparison for comparison expressions using multi-part keys

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/data-types

As the documentation mentions, the following syntax should be working :
This syntax can also be used with STRUCT comparison for comparison expressions using multi-part keys,

**e.g. in a WHERE clause:
WHERE (Key1,Key2) IN ( (12,34), (56,78) )**

I am trying the same query and I get a syntax error:

**SELECT a, b
FROM some_table
WHERE (a, b) IN ( (11332728, 126), (12312, 3131 ) );**

" Encountered " "," ", "" at line 3, column 10. Was expecting: ")" .."

Have you used this ? Can you please give me an example ?

Comment: Count `(` and count `)`. Same number?

Comment: I am sorry, I fixed it. In my real example, I have counted and they all look alright

Comment: Seems like the documentation is ahead of the product... (Your syntax is valid ANSI SQL.)

Comment: @onedaywhen, Yes, I know it's an ISO standard (ISO/IEC 9075), but it seems like most people and products still refer to it as ANSI SQL. And, yes no 2, this syntax was introduced in SQL-99.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to [enable standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/enabling-standard-sql) for the query before running it. Based on the error message, it sounds like you might be using legacy SQL.